# New to R, can someone explain me the code below?

Tags: r

```
printProp.xtab<-function(xtab,fmt='%s (%1.2f%%)',big.mark=',',na.print="NA",...) {
  ## PURPOSE: print an xtab with percentages in
  ## parentheses in addition to counts at every value.
  ## TODO: alignment the percentages at the decimal point.
  xtab.am<-addmargins(xtab)
  xtab.pt.am<-addmargins(prop.table(xtab,...))
  res<-sprintf(fmt,format(xtab.am,big.mark=big.mark),100*xtab.pt.am)
  attributes(res)<-attributes( xtab.am)
  print(quote=FALSE
       ,na.print=na.print
        ,res)
}
```

I know what he did with the print function and what he did in the first line. However, i'm not sure what he did in the curly brackets and  the Help function isn't really helpful for my problem.
Thanks for help!

Comment: How are you calling this and what are you calling it on? It helps to have some context

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand what a certain third-party function does, it usually helps to use some sample data, and step through the function line-by-line and inspect the output.

Let's use `mtcars` to create a 2-way contingency table with `xtabs`

```
xtab <- xtabs(~ gear + carb, data = mtcars)
#     carb
#gear 1 2 3 4 6 8
#   3 3 4 3 5 0 0
#   4 4 4 0 4 0 0
#   5 0 2 0 1 1 1
```

Then stepping through the individual steps from the function, `addmargins` adds the row and column margins (i.e. totals):

```
xtab.am <- addmargins(xtab)
xtab.am
#     carb
#gear   1  2  3  4  6  8 Sum
#  3    3  4  3  5  0  0  15
#  4    4  4  0  4  0  0  12
#  5    0  2  0  1  1  1   5
#  Sum  7 10  3 10  1  1  32
```

`prop.table` converts counts from a table into fractions (proportions)

```
xtab.pt.am<-addmargins(prop.table(xtab))
xtab.pt.am
#    carb
#gear        1       2       3       4       6       8     Sum
#  3   0.09375 0.12500 0.09375 0.15625 0.00000 0.00000 0.46875
#  4   0.12500 0.12500 0.00000 0.12500 0.00000 0.00000 0.37500
#  5   0.00000 0.06250 0.00000 0.03125 0.03125 0.03125 0.15625
#  Sum 0.21875 0.31250 0.09375 0.31250 0.03125 0.03125 1.00000
```

The last step is to combine the output from the count and proportion tables into a single table. To do that entries per cell are concatenated with `sprintf`; setting the `attributes` of the output vector to that of the original table makes sure that the output is again a table.

```
res <- sprintf("%s (%1.2f%%)", format(xtab.am,big.mark=","), 100 * xtab.pt.am)
attributes(res) <- attributes(xtab.am)
res
#     carb
#gear  1           2           3          4           6          8
#  3    3 (9.38%)   4 (12.50%)  3 (9.38%)  5 (15.62%)  0 (0.00%)  0 (0.00%)
#  4    4 (12.50%)  4 (12.50%)  0 (0.00%)  4 (12.50%)  0 (0.00%)  0 (0.00%)
#  5    0 (0.00%)   2 (6.25%)   0 (0.00%)  1 (3.12%)   1 (3.12%)  1 (3.12%)
#  Sum  7 (21.88%) 10 (31.25%)  3 (9.38%) 10 (31.25%)  1 (3.12%)  1 (3.12%)
#     carb
#gear  Sum
#  3   15 (46.88%)
#  4   12 (37.50%)
#  5    5 (15.62%)
#  Sum 32 (100.00%)
```